# Static File serving using Rack

Tags: ruby, rack, cuba

I have this block of code:

```
require "cuba"
require "mote"
require "mote/render"

Cuba.plugin(Mote::Render)

Cuba.use Rack::Static,
 # urls: %w[/index],
  root: File.expand_path("./public", __dir__)

Cuba.define do
  on(root) do
      render("index", title: "Welcome")
  end

end
```

and I'm trying to server the file in the public folder(which is in the same directory as the this file I'm running) named "index.html", but I'm getting an error on my website saying it cannot be found.

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /root/views/index.html.mote
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuba tries to render a template, so you can rename your file to .mote and it should render ok, or use something like this:

```
res.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
res.write(IO.read('/path/to/your/file.html'))
```

[Source](https://github.com/soveran/cuba/blob/master/lib/cuba/render.rb) is pretty clear on how the render function works.

Comment: Yes, like in their [readme](https://github.com/soveran/cuba/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

You can also set up your own custom routes for serving css/js without using Rack::Static

```
on 'css', extension('css') do
    res['Content-Type'] = 'text/css'
    res.write File.read(req.path)
end
```